# How to show a real-time count of the number of lines added per second to files?

Tags: awk, logs, tail

I'm working with a directory of multiple log files.

I'm trying to show a running count, updated periodically, of the number of lines written to each log file.

I need to see the number of lines written per period (e.g. per second) to each file, indexed by file name.

For bonus points, the lines should be sorted in decreasing order of the number of lines written per second.

This doesn't have to use something like `ncurses` (e.g. like top); it's ok if it simply writes updates every period (e.g. every second).

How do I accomplish this task?

---

I've included my solution as an answer, but I suspect there's a better way to do this... Hoping to learn a better way!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `watch` (read `man watch`):

```
watch --differences wc -l *.log
```

Comment: I deliberately wanted to avoid a solution like this since it requires counting all of the lines of all of the files on every iteration. Still, a totally valid and simple solution, especially for one-off usage. Thank you!

Comment: P.S. I didn't know about the [`--differences` parameter](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-watch-command/#highlighting-the-difference-between-updates) - thanks!

Comment: this is completly ineffective for large file count, and very long files - apache log for big loaded web service

Answer (score 2):

The best I could come up with was using `tail -f` along with `awk` and [`logtop`](https://julienpalard.github.io/logtop/):

`tail  -f * | awk '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print a}' | logtop`

This results in something like this:
[image]

Comment: N.B. For focusing in on a specific log file, try `tail -f filename | pv --line-mode --rate > /dev/null` [(source)](https://serverfault.com/a/641552/113436)

Comment: I still prefer this approach over the others since it doesn't require calling `wc -l *` on every iteration. It also has the added benefit of naturally excluding any files that aren't actively being changed.

Comment: very effective. with tail -F filename, it will switch dynamically to next physical log file. This is very good approach, because this will read only added content on the file. This effectively reduces system load, and don't load constantly big file content into ram cache. this avoids sweeping out any other important data, that increase system speed.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force approach with just mandatory Unix tools:

```
while :; do wc -l *; echo "-"; sleep 1; done |
awk '/^-/{print; next} {print $2, $1, $1-prev[$2]; prev[$2]=$1}'
```

The above will, every second, print each file name followed by the number of lines currently in the file and the change in the number of lines since the previous iteration. It'll do likewise for the total number of lines across all files.

Massage the awk output to suit and you can pipe it to `sort -k3,3n` to get it sorted as you like and throw in a `tput clear;` before each call to `wc -l` (or print the related escape sequence from awk each time it reads the first line after a `-`) if you just want to see the current output each time round the loop.

Comment: Similar to [this answer that uses `watch`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611430/65991), but with more flexibility (like the count of lines changed since the last iteration). Thank you!